# IDEA method breakpoints in the parent class effect corresponding methods in the subclass

Tags: java

When debugging Java code in IntelliJ IDEA, breakpoints set on methods in the parent class will take effect on corresponding methods in the subclass, even if the declaration and instantiation are for the subclass itself.

```
public class Debug02 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Son instance = new Son();
        instance.test();
    }
}

class Father{
    public void test(){//add method breakpoints here
        System.out.println("Father : test1");
        System.out.println("Father : test2");
    }
}

class Son extends Father{
    @Override
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("Son : test1");
        System.out.println("Son : test2");
    }
}
```

After starting the debug session, it automatically pauses at the first line of the "test" method in the "Son" class.

Please tell why?

Comment: This seems to be how method breakpoints work (from the [IntelliJ IDEA documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2023.1/using-breakpoints.html#breakpoint-types): **Method breakpoints**: suspend the program upon entering or exiting the specified method **or one of its implementations**, allowing you to check the method's entry/exit conditions)